# Firestore Client' not found

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to both PHP and Firebase. I tried to use firestore on a php site.

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

initialize();




function initialize()
{
    // Create the Cloud Firestore client
    $db = new FirestoreClient();
    printf('Created Cloud Firestore client with default project ID.' . PHP_EOL);
}
```

but the there's a Fatal error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 37

I followed quick start tutorial - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

I'm using debian 9 VPS with PHP 5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem got fixed. If anyone having same problem.  I added `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of page. And Make sure to add `extension=grpc.so`  to both php.ini files ( one inside apache 2 folder other inside cli folder) and restart apache.   here is my new code

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

initialize();

function initialize()
{
    // Create the Cloud Firestore client
    $db = new FirestoreClient();
    printf('Created Cloud Firestore client with default project ID.' . PHP_EOL);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you followed [all of the steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) carefully?

Namely, please check you've added the library:

```
composer require google/cloud-firestore
```

and that you've added the following to the top of your file:

```
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
```

Comment: Yes did both things

Answer (score 0):

The Class library is not accessible from your `test.php` file.

Use a bootstrap to load `Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient` or include it  manually in your script.

Comment: I actually Manually included use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
 in my php script

Comment: you should share as much of you code to make clear what you included and how you did it